# Qt install offline

Tags: installation, qt

Is it possible to install Qt toolkit without internet connection?

I downloaded offline installer, but to begin installation process I need to log in *Qt Account*. Is there some way to skip this step? Or situation is something like this: *no internet - no Qt*?

---

**OS** Lubuntu 64-bit
**Qt** Qt 5.7.0 for Android (Linux 64-bit, 769 MB)

Comment: The offline installer just means you don't download the install files, it doesn't mean, you don't need a QT account.

Comment: Which OS are you using and which bundle did you download?

Comment: @Ramhound IMHO, the only purpose of an offline installer is to be able to install its content on an isolated device with no possible network or internet access. It sounds incompatible with an online checking of a user account.

Comment: @A.Loiseau - Just because you can install a program offline does not mean the program can't require internet to fully function.  I am going to guess the QT installer does allow you to skip the account step though.

Comment: Just as a heads up, the online installer you get from Qt no longer allows you to download Qt 5.7, but you can find it on some other websites, e.g., http://qtmirror.ics.com/pub/qtproject/official_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0/ -- I would strongly recommend that you back the files you need up to a secure location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The installer is only asking for login credentials when it can reach the internet, so if you don't have network access, you will have the skip button.

If you want to deploy it without logging in—even when the PC is connected to the internet—you have to temporarily delete the default route (0.0.0.0). That way the installer cannot contact the server and will provide you with the skip button.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](https://forum.qt.io/topic/60046/mandatory-qt-account-in-installer), you should have a "skip" button if you clear all Qt account fields.

Comment: Hmm the skip button seems to have disappeared again...  Installing Qt 5.9.4 and 5.9.6 which previously had the skip button...

Answer (score 2):

On the 5.12.9 installer's Welcome screen, if you click on Settings, you can configure a proxy. I just gave it a non-existent IP/port. It eventually gave up and let me proceed without entering account info.

No modification with your routing table needed.

Comment: that actually worked for me, nice one!